# Laravel, attaching related data to json response

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to attach a role and return the user with his roles:

```
# Attach role depending on input 'type'
$role = Input::get('type');
$user->assignRoleByName($role);

# Return response
return Response::json(array(
    'user' => $user,
    'roles' => $user->roles
));
```

The strange thing is that when I have the above response, the roles are included in the 'user' section *and* the 'roles' section (as I would have imagined). **Yet, when I remove the 'roles' section, the roles also disappear from the 'user' section**.

What I want is to return the role with the user, using:

```
# Return response
return Response::json(array(
    'user' => $user
));
```

In my User.php model:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role')->withTimestamps();
}

public function assignRoleByName($name)
{
    $roles = Role::all();

    foreach ($roles as $role)
    {
        if ($role->name == $name) 
        {
            $this->roles()->attach($role);
        }
    }

}
```

And the pivot table migration:

```
Schema::create('role_user', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like,

```
$userId = 1; // find the user
$userWithRoles = $user->with('roles')->where('id' , '=', $userId)->get()->toArray(); // get all roles of the user with user details.

return Response::json(array(
    'user' => $userWithRoles
));
```

don't forget to relate the 2 table with foreign keys.

Comment: why using the `where` method on primary key ? the `find` method was made to make it cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You may try this (Using `load`):

```
# Return response
return Response::json(array(
    'user' => $user->load('roles')
));
```

For more information, check `Lazy Eager Loading` on [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) Section in `Eloquent`.